# how to read line by line in file and also check line is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to read line by line in a file using node js.but I have doubt for how to check line is empty or not in a file using node js

**data.js**

```
console.log("123")

console.log("123")


console.log("123")



console.log("123")
```

**file.js**

```
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
                    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data.js')
                  });
                  lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
                    console.log('Line from file:', line);
                  });
```

**I got this output**

```
Line from file: console.log("123")  
Line from file:                    
Line from file: console.log("123")  
Line from file:                    
Line from file:                    
Line from file: console.log("123")  
Line from file:                    
Line from file:                     
Line from file:                    
Line from file: console.log("123")
```

but I want how to check line is empty or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking the length of the string for each line:

```
var count = 0;
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: require('fs').createReadStream('./data.js')
});
lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    ++count;  // keep a count of number of lines
    if (line.length > 0) {
        console.log('Line from file:', line);
    }
});
```

The above logic would only log non empty inputs, but you may change it to whatever you want.

Comment: and also another doubt how to check how many lines in file using node js